# Como filtrar información en una VISTA por registro?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, vistas

Buen día.

Me pudieran ayudar a filtrar información de esta VISTA en MYSQL?, lo que quiero hacer es obtener el total   SUM(Cantidad) as Suma por registro de contrato, ya que actualmente obtengo el total de la columna.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tablacom AS
SELECT id_pre, NoContrato, Nombre, ApellidoMa, ApellidoPa, Domicilio, Paquete, Precio,
        
     SUM(Cantidad) as Suma 
     
FROM bd.clientes INNER JOIN bd.recibos USING(NoContrato)

  SUM(Cantidad) as Suma es de la segunda tabla (bd.recibos)
```

Espero darme a entender, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

creo entender el problema que estas teniendo,si no me equivoco te esta sacando el total de todos ya que no estas agrupando,tendrás que pensar como poder agrupar en la tabla bd.recibos para que te saque el total por cada número de contrato.

```
select no_contrato,sum(cantidad),bd.clientes.* from bd.recibos
INNER JOIN bd.clientes  USING(NoContrato)
group by no_contrato
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, en efecto, ese es mi problema, no sé como agrupar sum(cantidad) por registro, solo lo he podido hacer asignando un registro 

SELECT SUM(R.Cantidad) as Suma FROM recibos R, clientes C WHERE R.NoContrato = C.NoContrato AND C.NoContrato = '25'

Comment: Para agrupar tienes que utilizar "GROUP BY (LO QUE QUIERES AGRUPAR)". En este caso NoContrato de esta forma podrás ver la suma por cada número de contrato.

Comment: Buen día, Gonzalo Martí Posthuma muchas gracias, con tu ayuda pude hacer un query que agrupe y haga una vista.